# Zero value for Sensor.timestamp

Tags: javascript, sensors

I can't seem to able to find detailed information on `Sensor.timestamp` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Sensor/timestamp)).

- Is the timestamp absolute or relative?
- What is the zero value?
- Are the values measured in milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click through into [the spec for High Resolution Time Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/#dom-domhighrestimestamp), these questions are answerable in regards to the `timestamp` getter for `Sensor`, which is returned as a [`DOMHighResTimeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp):

> - Is the timestamp absolute or relative?

"*Absolute*" here is a bit vague, and I'm not sure what your reference point for this term would be. Formally defined, `timestamp` is "*measured relative from the time origin, global monotonic clock, or a time value that represents a duration between two `DOMHighResTimeStamp`s*". ([Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/#sec-domhighrestimestamp))

> - What is the zero value?

TL;DR - in this specific context, it *should* be the Unix epoch (1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

This is a bit more complicated to answer and just a bit more opaque than is helpful, but the "zero value" for a `DOMHighResTimeStamp` is referred to in the spec as a *time origin*. [The formal definition of a time origin](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/#dfn-time-origin) is a bit verbose; however in this context since `Sensor` (or, more importantly, its derived classes) is not a `Window` nor a `WorkerGlobalScope` object, the time origin would be `undefined` and thus (per the definition above) would default to something called the [*global monotonic clock*](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/#dfn-global-monotonic-clock) which pins "zero" to the Unix epoch (1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC) per [the ECMA-262 definition of `time` (§21.4.1.1)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-time-values-and-time-range).

> - Are the values measured in milliseconds?

Yes - "*The `DOMHighResTimeStamp` type is used to store a time value in milliseconds*" ([Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/#dom-domhighrestimestamp)).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [esqew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/269970/esqew), for pointing me in the right direction.

In the context of a browser-based JavaScript app, the **timestamp value is relative with the time origin being the time when the browsing context** was first created.